# Sed match between matching curling brackets

Tags: regex, sed

I have following file:

```
Items{
 Item{
    car "blue"
    tire 4
  }
 Item{
    car "yellow"
    tire 0
 }
}
Orders{
 Order{
    ID 123
    Cost 123
 }
 Order{
    ID 231
    Cost 2
 }
}
```

And I need **in sed** to match everything between Items{ and the last matching } of that group... as it is now I can do it with:

```
sed -n /Items/,/^\}/p
```

The problem is, that the file is not space sensitive and the other brackets of the subcategory can be also at the start of the line... any idea how to universally match it ? it need to be in sed, as I need that "match" later to pinpoint edits...

Edited the sample file

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Can't you match in the `/Items/,/Orders/` range and then just remove the last line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest expected results is:
Items{
 Item{
    car "blue"
    tire 4
 }
 Item{
    car "yellow"
    tire 0
}

Comment: @choroba unfortunately the name of the next category is not the same all the time, its super messy file and going over like 20 of them now every one is slightly different in formatting and the main category I'm after can be anywhere in the document

Comment: Should each item be closed ? The 'Items' is not closed before 'Orders' is started. Can you clarify the rules of this format ?

Comment: @dash-o sorry I did not notice i pasted it wrongly, yes the items are closed  its always { and ending }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few choices to attack the problem

1. Convert the file to standard format (XML, JSON), and use standard tools (xml, xsltproc or jq) to parse the file.
2. Pretty-print the file, and then use the indentation to identify block ends.
3. Write custom tokenizer, and count open/close braces.

Going for #2, using `perl` to build pretty-print formatter. It is possible extract using any tool (sed, awk, ...).

```
perl pp-data.pl filename.txt | sed -n 'sed -n '/^Items/,/^}/p'
```

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# pp-data.pl
use strict ;
my $d = eval { local $/ ; <> } ;
my $l = 0 ;
my $n = 0 ;
while ( $d =~ /({|}|\w+|"[^"]*")/g ) {
        my $w = $1 ;

        $l-- if $w eq '}' ;

        print $n ? " " : (" " x ($l * 2)), $w ;
        $n++ ;

        if ( $w eq "{" ) {
                $l++ ;
                $n = 0 ;
        } elsif ( $w eq "}" ) {
                $n = 0 ;
        } elsif ( $n == 2 ) {
                $n = 0 ;
        } ;
        print "\n" unless $n ;
} ;
1;
```

For the input in the answer, the parsed output will look like:

```
Items {
  Item {
    car "blue"
    tire 4
  }
  Item {
    car "yellow"
    tire 0
  }
}
Orders {
  Order {
    ID 123
    Cost 123
  }
  Order {
    ID 231
    Cost 2
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, reformatting the file is probably the best way to go